# byte[] to RubyString for string xor in JRuby Java Extension

Tags: java, jruby, jruby-java-interop

I'm trying to implement a Java extension for JRuby to perform string xors. I'm just uncertain how to type cast a byte array into a `RubyString`:

```
public static RubyString xor(ThreadContext context,  IRubyObject self, RubyString x, RubyString y) {
    byte[] xBytes = x.getBytes();
    byte[] yBytes = y.getBytes();

    int length = yBytes.length < xBytes.length ? yBytes.length : xBytes.length;

    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        xBytes[i] = (byte) (xBytes[i] ^ yBytes[i]);
    }

    // How to return a RubyString with xBytes as its content?
}
```

Also, how would one perform the same operation in-place (i.e. `x`s value is updated)?

Comment: There are constructors on RubyString that accept a `byte[]` here `org.jruby.RubyString.RubyString(Ruby runtime, RubyClass rubyClass, byte[] value)` not sure if that's applicable in this instance?

Comment: Looks promising. Any idea what the `rubyClass` argument is supposed to be?

Comment: Not sure about that argument unfortunately. I've used Jruby for years, but haven't tried writing an extension before.  Dropping by the #jruby channel on freenode irc may be the quickest way to get some more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return context.runtime.newString(new ByteList(xBytes, false));`

Comment: What is this? Some explanation would be nice. If you don't want to do that, post a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You'll first need to wrap the bytes in a [`ByteList`](https://github.com/jruby/bytelist/blob/c5f23cb8ef5ecad68f26ace25d937a5bfd159606/src/org/jruby/util/ByteList.java#L131): `new ByteList(xBytes, false)`. The last parameter (`Boolean copy`) dictates whether to wrap a copy of the Byte array.

To update the string in place, use `[RubyString#setValue()][2]`:

```
x.setValue(new ByteList(xBytes, false);
return x;
```

To return a new `RubyString`, you can pass that list to the current runtime's [`#newString()`](http://jruby.org/apidocs/org/jruby/Ruby.html#newString(org.jruby.util.ByteList)):

```
return context.runtime.newString(new ByteList(xBytes, false));
```